# How to keep Greater Than and Less Than Signs as They are in Text Editor?

Tags: javascript, summernote

I initialize summernote editor to my textarea as below:

```js
$('#summernote').summernote({
  height: 300
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.5.0/summernote.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.5.0/summernote.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.5.0/summernote-bs3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<textarea name="summernote" id="summernote" cols="30" rows="10">
</textarea>
```

It was working just fine, until I tried to typed in greater than (>) and less than (<) signs alone, the editor converted them to `&gt;` and `&lt;` respectively.

Moreover, in [summernote editor](https://summernote.org/) does not document about how to keep these signs as it is.

How can I keep `<` and `>` as they are in editor ? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should report to the authors. Naught you can do about it unless you're going to do superhero and deep dive into the code yourself. And the library doesn't even look open source

Comment: @Merigold, thanks, I think it is open source since there is nowhere say about price. I'm pretty sure that there could be somewhere to overcome this.

Comment: Price has nothing to do with openness. But there's a link to their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/) at the top right corner of the homepage.

Comment: @AuxTaco, thanks. I will post to them as a new issue. I believe there would be a workaround. Thanks.